# After using offset and applying "show()" to a div, it disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dropdown menu that "onmousedown" appears were the mouse position is.

so:

```
function show_menu(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        // ### do things ###
    } else {
        var abc = $("#right-side-calendar-area").offset();
        var top = event.pageY - abc.top;
        var left = event.pageX - abc.left;

        $("#menu").css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: top,
            left: left
        }).show();
    }
}
```

my menu appears (onmousedown)  and disappeares (onmouseup). inspecting the html code I see a "display:none".

another strange think if I do only this change:

```
var top = event.pageY - 100;
```

it works correctly.

Note: I don't have any other function/method/class for this menu.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Could you add a [mcve] so we understand what you're asking?

Comment: Create a demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/) pls.

Comment: after creatin a demo, I resolved it! :D thanks